# Is it possible with javers to ignore sequence change of Java objects?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, javers

I have nested Java objects. The Json of it (for example) looks like below:
First object’s Json:

```
{
  ClassId : 1,
  OfficeLocation: “UK”,
  “Employees”: [{
     ClassId: 2,
     FirstName: “Bob”,
     LastName: “Smith”
   },
   {
     ClassId: 3,
     FirstName: “Tim”,
     LastName: “Timothy”
   }]
}
```

Second object’s json:

```
{
  ClassId : 1,
  OfficeLocation: “UK”,
  “Employees”: [{
     ClassId: 3,
     FirstName: “Tim”,
     LastName: “Timothy”
   },
   {
     ClassId: 2,
     FirstName: “Bob”,
     LastName: “Smith”
   }]
}
```

I want to ignore the change if its just a sequence change as above. But currently, javers is giving me Diff result as valueAdded and ValueRemoved. I am using Javers 3.1.0. Is there anyway to do this?

In my entity class I have added @Id annotation to ClassId. But still not able to achieve expected results. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can store sorted data

Comment: Thanks Alxander! I thought of that option but my actual object json is very complex and big. So just curious if there is any other option available apart from sorting.

Comment: You mean Is it possible with javers to ignore the ordering of elements in a List?

Comment: @Bartek yes. Or at least some kind of flag that will indicate its sequence change.

Comment: but your question says the opposite ...

Comment: @Bartek Thanks.. I have corrected the heading now.  I have explained my problem in the description also- I want to ignore order change!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions.

First one (recommended) - use the right collection type. List is an ordered collection, use Set if you don't care about ordering.

Second solution. If you cant change Lists to Sets, use `ListCompareAlgorithm.AS_SET` and keep your data in Lists.

```java
javersBuilder.withListCompareAlgorithm(ListCompareAlgorithm.AS_SET)
```

If `AS_SET` is selected, Javers compares Lists like Sets (all elements from Lists are copied to Sets before comparison).